# How to completely remove oracal and open JDK from ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, jdk

I am getting a error with oracal jdk 8, when I am running ubuntu software update in my ubuntu 16.04. So I need to uninstall all JDK form ubuntu. How to ensure that how many jdk installed in my ubuntu-pc. And also how to remove all jdk from my pc.

Comment: If you provide the exact commands and output someone might have a chance to help you.

Comment: No. I want to know how many JDK installed in my Ubuntu @Soren. Like one open-jdk7 and one oracal-jdk8.